# Avoid to specity template argument when using a function

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I want to write a template function that take a `std::function` as argument, something like:

```
 template<typename T>
 void registerDelegate(std::function<void(const T&)> d) {
   d(T{});
 }
```

When I want to use it, I need to write in an explicit way the `T` template argument:

```
 auto d = [](const std::string& message) { int i = 0; };
 registerDelegate<std::string>(d);
```

that's annoying since I've already defined it in the lambda. Is there a way to avoid it and simply write:

```
registerDelegate(d);
```

When I want to use the function, while always knowing what T is?

Comment: I would try to make a [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) work here, it should be fairly easy for a non-capturing lambda. Might be able to make it work for a capturing one, with some sweat and tears. This would need deep hacking to investigate.

Comment: You could write `registerDelegate(std::function(d));` or `std::function d = [](std::string) {...}; registerDelegate(d);`. The compiler does not consider implicit conversion when trying to select a parametrization for `registerDelegate`, because it can't. Every specialization of `std::function<...>` could have been specialized to support all kinds of crazy conversions and the compiler could not possibly try them all. So you tell the compiler which one to use, either by having a `std::function<void(std::string)>` as argument or by explicitly specifying `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could forward whatever functor that is supplied to `registerDelegate` to a lambda (or function template ) taking a `std::function<void(const T&>` to deduce `T`.

```cpp
template <class F>
void registerDelegate(F&& d) {
    []<class T>(std::function<void(const T&)> del) {
        del(T{});
    }(std::function(std::forward<F>(d))); // use std::function's deduction guides
}
```

---

Instead of changing your current function template which already matches on `std::function<void(const T&)>`, you could add a function template for functors/functions not already wrapped up in a `std::function`:

```cpp
template<class F>
decltype(auto) registerDelegate(F&& func) {
    // call your already existing function:
    return registerDelegate(std::function(std::forward<F>(func)));
    //                           ^ use std::function's deduction guides
}
```

Comment: What if instead of a `std::function`, I've my own delegate (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170503/The-Impossibly-Fast-Cplusplus-Delegates-Fixed)?

Comment: @Jepessen That was quite a lenghty article. :) Do you mean that your function still takes a `std::function<void(const T&)>` but you want it to match on something that `std::function` can't deduce the type for?

Comment: Basically yes. We are using a custom delegate inspired by the article linked in my previous comment, because it's usually faster than `std::function`. So we use this class instead of std::function in our code. I've used it in the example only to have the idea of what I need, but now I think that I have to write my delegate deduction guides...

Comment: @Jepessen I see. Yes, for the same solution to work for a non-`std::function` type, it'd need similar deduction guides. Another note: As I implied in the answer, you could forward the `F` function to your existing function template taking a `std::function<void(const T&>` too. I added that to the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage `std::function`'s deduction guides:

```
template<class Functor>
void registerDelegate(Functor&& functor)
{
   std::function f = functor;
   (void) f;
}
```

If you *need* to access the argument type:

```
template<class Functor>
auto to_function(Functor&& functor)
{
    std::function f = functor;
    return f;
}
 
template<class Arg>
void registerDelegate(std::function<void(const Arg&)> d) {
    d(Arg{});
}

auto d = [](std::string const&){};
registerDelegate(to_function(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction. If you want to deduce `T` in `registerDelegate`, you need a `std::function`, not just something convertible to `std::function`.

In C++17, this is easily solved by using class template argument deduction, and the [`std::function` deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides).

```cpp
auto d = [](std::string const&){};
registerDelegate(std::function{d});
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xj9cxrqc1)*.